# How to get the byte array data from Reference-arithmetic-coding result

Tags: java

I am trying to implement arithmetic coding using Java,and I found this project:[Reference-arithmetic-coding](https://github.com/nayuki/Reference-arithmetic-coding). But its' input and output are both file, I wanna get the byte array that is the coding result from `AdaptiveArithmeticCompress.compress()`. Here is what I did:
I add a function in class `AdaptiveArithmeticCompress` named `AACompress`:

```
public static byte[] AACompress(short[] delta) throws  IOException{
    byte[] bytedelta = TypeConversion.ShortToByte_little(delta);
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytedelta);
    BitOutputStream out = new BitOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream());

    compress(bis,out);
    return out.toBytearray();
}
```

and create `out.toBytearray()` to convert outputstream to byte array.

```
public byte[] toBytearray() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = (ByteArrayOutputStream) output;
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

But when I compared result byte array with result file which is output of `AdaptiveArithmeticCompress.compress(InputStream in, BitOutputStream out)`, I found that

```
short[] delta = ...;
byte[] coding = AdaptiveArithmeticCompress.AACompress(delta);
```

`coding.length` is 1 less than `out.buf.length`, the last byte of `out.buf` is missing, so the coding result is wrong.
I am new to Java, this problem has been confusing me several days. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding a `close` method in `ArithmeticEncoder` class

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    output.close();
}
```

And the missing byte has been added into outputstream.